# Cable routing around bottom bracket

Tags: cable, cable-routing

See picture attached of a point in the rear derallier cable routing - should I put something in there to prevent rubbing (I can't fit any brake or gear housing in there - so if so what should I use?), or is the cable fine going naked through the braze-on?

Ditto for the other side and the front derallier, which goes through a series of curves and up into the derallier.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I've never seen anything like that so I don't have an answer for you, but I'm curious - what kind of bike is that?

Comment: It is a 1979 falcon frame, with extensive modifications to take a modern drive system & a brand new coat of paint.

Comment: Is that one of the modifications?

Comment: I'm not actually sure - I think it might be original.  It guides the rear mech cable, originally from a downtube shifter, now from a campag cable stop, which takes the cable from the brifter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to put anything in there. If you're really concerned get teflon coated cables.

Those kinds of braze on cable guides were "standard" issue on well made lugged steel bikes until the early 80's or so. ( Cheap bikes came with bolt on versions of the same guides. ) They worked just fine even with old style cables that were much rougher than current cables. ( Current cables are pulled through a die to make them as round and smooth as possible and are also generally a much more rust resistant steel. )

Answer (score 1):

I know that the Jagwire  brand mountain cable sets come with a small diameter tube that cover all the exposed cables. I used the extra pieces on my old Giant. It did seem to make the cable movement smoother although it is subjective. I have never seen it available in single lengths. You could check your LBS to see if they have any short pieces or look in a local hardware/ home center for small diameter tubing.

Comment: Some brake cable housings have teflon inner tubing. Get a 3 inch piece and slip the teflon tube over greased the derailleur cable. I've done that in a similar case. It works perfectly.

Comment: @Carel How would I go about getting the teflon out?  Also, is it strictly necessary?  Or will it just protect the paintwork?

Comment: The teflon tube is quite loose inside the steel casing. It can easily pushed out especially if it is a short length. It will reduce the friction of the cable on the frame, but strictly speaking it is not necessary.

Comment: As you only need short lengths, the inner of a V-Brake noodle is easy to remove and use here. They are also cheap and old, rusted ones are free. It will improve the cable smoothness in use. @7thGalaxy

Answer (score 0):

I honestly haven't tried but you could probably squeeze a bowden cable in there. Specifically, those types that 3D printers use. If I were to go with such, I'd also lubricate the cables with light grease or chain lube just to be sure.